# HTC phone uses different theme while creating fragment the first time and after orientation change

Tags: android, user-interface, themes, htc-android

I instantiate Fragment in the activity in a following manner:

```
Fragment fragment = new SimpleTestFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

And now created fragment has no style applied to it, by what I mean textviews have white text etc. However after rotation the style gets applied properly.

One solution would be to use new, wrapped context in the onCreateView, however doing so in 10+ fragments seems unnecessary and just simply annoying.

And here is my question: Do you know of any other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: How do you apply the theme?

Comment: Thanks for that, I applied theme to the application not the activity. Other "flavours" of Android did understand that, HTC Sense needed implicit declaration for the activity to grasp which theme to apply from the start. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Make sure that you apply theme in the manifest to each of the declared activities, not only for the application.